# How to increase laser output?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser

In a semiconductor laser, light is emitted from the pn junction and guided across the laser length to come out from the mirrors. During this travel across the length of laser, the photons enter the p-type or n-type semiconductor and thus the light output decreases. Can we stop these from entering the p or n-type semiconductor so that they are confined in the junction only and reach the mirrors without attenuation?

Answer (score 2):

Well, typically, the semiconductor material layers are stacked vertically, while the light propagates horizontally (within the plane of the layers). The gain region is relatively thin, so the optical mode is always overlapping the $n$ or $p$ lossy regions. So often one design goal is indeed to confine the mode to increase overlap with the gain region and reduce overlap with the lossy regions. But the are many trade-offs in these designs, so it can be easier said than done.